# Log disk clean up VBScript

Tags: vbscript

So i have a little script that runs a disk clean up, but i want to log this. Is it possible via f.writeline or something? I already tryed to add some write lines but that didnt work, so i removed these..

```
Option Explicit 
On Error Resume Next 

SetRegKeys 
DoCleanup 


Sub DoCleanup() 
Dim WshShell 
Set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cleanmgr /sagerun:1" 
End Sub 

Sub SetRegKeys 
Dim strKeyPath 
Dim strComputer 
Dim objReg 
Dim arrSubKeys 
Dim SubKey 
Dim strValueName 
Dim fso
Const HKLM=&H80000002

strKeyPath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches" 
strComputer="." 
strValueName="StateFlags0001" 

Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.Enumkey HKLM ,strKeyPath,arrSubKeys 

For Each SubKey In arrSubKeys 

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath & "\" & SubKey,strValueName,2 

Next 

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a standard subroutine that I use to log to an output file (path "logfileName" specified at the top of the script) that also appends the time on each line:

```
Sub Logwrite (aMsg)
   Dim a
   Const ForAppending = 8

   ' This Appends a line of text to a Logwrite file
   ' creating it if required
   If Len(aMsg) = 0 Then
      If fso.FileExists(logfileName) Then fso.DeleteFile(logfileName)
      Exit Sub
   End If

   Set a = fso.OpenTextFile(logfileName, ForAppending, TRUE, 0)
   a.WriteLine(Now() & " -- " & aMsg)
   a.Close
   Set a = Nothing

End Sub
```

For example, you can call the subroutine in the For Each loop, and you can specify the message that gets logged:

```
For Each SubKey In arrSubKeys 

   objReg.SetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath & "\" & SubKey,strValueName,2 
   Logwrite "Set value for " & strKeyPath & "\" & SubKey & " to " & strValueName

Next
```

Note that if I want to erase the previous file if it exists, then I will first call the subroutine at the top of the script with a blank message to log -- `Logwrite ""` -- which tells it to delete the previous log file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! So far i added your script to my script, but it wont work, i changed the 'logfilename' to 'C:\Log.txt'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone who could help me out with this? Kind regards